# Remove partial similar words from longest phrase

Tags: php, string

Please consider this example

```
Array
(
   [1] => search engine optimization
   [2] => engine optimization
   [0] => search engine
)
```

I want to remove engine optimization and search engine because these words are already in the longest phrase. These words are not hard coded, the above result is generated by a function. I did my best to code it but couldn't solve this problem.

### EDIT

This is my attempt, looks like people here don't trust and they are good at pressing vote down button. My approach is not adequate so I didn't bother to share it here.

```
$result = array('search engine', 'search engine optimization', 'engine optimization');
uasort($result, 'string_word_length');

foreach($result as $key=>$phrase) {
  if( ($found = array_find($phrase, $result, $key)) != FALSE) {
     unset($result[$found]);
  }
}

function array_find($needle, $haystack, $skip_key = 0) {
    if(!is_array($haystack)) return false;
        foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
            if($skip_key != $key && strpos($value, $needle)!==false) {
                 echo 'Poped ', $value, ' -- ', $key, ' -- ', $skip_key, '<br />';
                 return $key;
           }
    }
   return false;
}
function string_word_length($a,$b){
   return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
}
```

Comment: _"My approach is not adequate so I didn't bother to share it here."_ The reason to share your code, especially when it is "not adequate," is so that we can help you with _your_ programming problem. The forum is not the place to ask that your programming be done for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this (supposing you use **php >= 5.3**):

```
$src = array('search engine optimization',
    'engine optimization',
    'search engine');

$src_array = array();
foreach ($src as $val) {
    $src_array[] = explode(' ', $val);
}

usort($src_array, function($a, $b) { return count($a) > count($b); });

foreach ($src_array as $key => $val) {
    if ($key + 1 < count($src_array)) {
        foreach ($val as $word_key => $word){
            for ($i = $key + 1; $i <= count($src_array) - 1; $i++) {
                if (in_array($word, $src_array[$i])) {
                    unset($src_array[$key][$word_key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$result = array_filter($src_array, function($i) { return count($i) > 0; });
$result = array_map(function($i) { return implode(' ', $i); }, $result);
$result = array_values($result);

var_dump($result);
```

For those who doesn't have php 5.3 installed here is the output result: `array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "search engine optimization" }`

Comment: @Jared Farrish: oh yes, 5.3. Thanks ;-) Anyway, it could be rewritten easily with explicit functions or `create_function()`